# Check if phone is face down

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

What do I need to import or access on the phone to check these values?
I know there is a device orientation, but I need to know if the phone is face down, or if the phone is close to an object!

Comment: Just enable proximity monitoring

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidevice/1620017-proximitymonitoringenabled?language=objc

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uideviceorientation/1620035-facedown

Comment: Use the `orientation` prop of the `UIDevice` https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidevice

Comment: does this allow for a completion handler or if the device orientation is face down. Will I be able to close the app, or open a view etc?

Comment: This seems to not be working on my ipad air